# P-adic valuation prime lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've been trying to prove:

$$ \nu_{{n}} \left(\prod^{n-1}_{j=1} {n\choose j} \right)=n-1 \quad \operatorname{if and only if} \quad n \in \mathbb P\cup{\{1}\}$$

From the basic properties of the p-adic order of a number:

$$\nu_{{p}} \left( {\frac {n!}{j!\, \left( n-j \right) !}} \right) =\nu_
{{p}} \left( n! \right) -(\nu_{{p}} \left( j! \right) +\nu_{{p}}
 \left(  \left( n-j \right) ! \right)) 
$$

Therefore:

$$\nu_{{p}} \left(\prod^{n-1}_{j=1} {\frac {n!}{j!\, \left( n-j \right) !}} \right) =\sum^{n-1}_{j=1}\Bigl(\nu_
{{p}} \left( n! \right) -(\nu_{{p}} \left( j! \right) +\nu_{{p}}
 \left(  \left( n-j \right) ! \right))\Bigr)=(n-1)\nu_
{{p}} \left( n! \right)-\sum^{n-1}_{j=1}(\nu_{{p}} \left( j! \right) +\nu_{{p}}
 \left(  \left( n-j \right) ! \right))
$$

Allowing us to restate the original lemma as:

$$(n-1)\nu_
{{n}} \left( n! \right)-\sum^{n-1}_{j=1}(\nu_{{n}} \left( j! \right) +\nu_{{n}}
 \left(  \left( n-j \right) ! \right))=n-1  \quad \operatorname{if and only if} \quad n \in \mathbb P\cup{\{1}\}$$

But I don't feel as if I have gotten anywhere here.

I then wanted to just say the denominator of 
$$\frac{\prod^{n-1}_{j=1} {n\choose j}}{n^n}$$

is $n$ if and only if $n$ is prime or $n=1$, but that's just handballing the absence of  proof to another statement really.

Comment: I’m sorry, what is $v_n$ for $n$ nonprime?

Comment: less than $0 \leq \nu_{{n}} \left(\prod^{n-1}_{j=1} {n\choose j} \right) \lt n-1$ if $n$ is non prime

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear. I was asking for a *definition* of $v_n(m)$ for integers $m$.

Comment: The largest exponent of $n$ that is a divisor of $m$

Comment: so as an example $$\nu_{{32}} \left(\prod^{31}_{j=1} {32\choose j} \right)=25$$

Comment: where as $$\nu_{{31}} \left(\prod^{30}_{j=1} {31\choose j} \right)=30$$

Comment: Then your statement that $v_n(n!)=1$ is not correct, since $v_6(6!)=2$.

Comment: sorry, the largest exponent $\nu$ for which $n^{\nu}$ is a divisor of $m$

Comment: ah ok thanks I will change this

Comment: This is what lead to me making this incorrect statement: $$\nu_{{p}} \left( n! \right) =\sum _{j=1}^{ \lfloor {\frac {   \ln (n) }{\ln \left( p \right) }} \rfloor +1} \Bigl\lfloor {\frac {n}{{p}^{j}}} \Bigr\rfloor$$

Comment: $$\nu_{{n}} \left( n! \right) =\sum _{j=1}^{ \lfloor {\frac {   \ln (n) }{\ln \left( n\right) }} \rfloor +1} \Bigl\lfloor {\frac {n}{{n}^{j}}} \Bigr\rfloor$$

Comment: $$\nu_{{n}} \left( n! \right) =\sum _{j=1}^{ 2} \Bigl\lfloor {\frac {n}{{n}^{j}}} \Bigr\rfloor$$

Comment: I forgot that this formula can only be used for prime $p$.